# A library that wraps java io not to force client to use checking exception

Tags: java, exception

Is there some library that would provide kind of wrapper around java io, that would allow not to catch all exceptions, to make code cleaner and simpler to understand.

Let' say I do not want to have this:

```
public void loadSomething(InputStream in) throws SomeCheckingException {

   BufferedReader reader = getReader(in);

    try {
      someId = reader.readLine();
      ...

    } catch(IOException ex) {
      ...        
    } finally {
        try {
        reader.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        ...
        } 
    }
 }
```

I would prefer to have this:

```
public void loadSomething(InputStream in) throws RuntimeException {

 someId = getReader(in).readLine();

}
```

This library would handle exception inside getReader and would close the `inputstream`, puts some error to the log (if configured), throws exception out of the method to client. And the client, if he wants, he would handle it.

On the client:

```
try {
  loadSomething(...)
} catch(RuntimeException ex) {...}
```

Comment: How could the client throw the exception, when it appears it's not declared to throw `IOException`?

Comment: Also note that your first bit of code isn't even valid - you can't put a `catch` block after a `finally` block.

Comment: If you want to make classes easier to read, simply change the method header so it includes a `throws <ExceptionType>`. Then include the `try catch` in the code that uses it.

Comment: Have you considered using the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement? Doing so would considerably reduce the bulkiness of your first method.

Comment: If the method takes a stream as argument, it should generally not close it. Let the opener of the stream close it. And since the caller opens the stream, it probably already deals with IOException, so you should simply throw IOException from this method, and let the caller handle the IOException

Comment: to: Jon Skeet - the client will handle it but not throw.

Comment: @JB Spring Framework, for example, cares about closing sessions automatically while working with database connection. I would like to have same logic related to stream.

Comment: @ses: that's what the try-with-resources construct is all about. But I don't see how it relates to your question and to the fact that IOException is a checked exception.

Answer (score 2):

> I would prefer to have this:
>
> ```
> public void loadSomething(InputStream in) {
>
>     consoleId = getReader(in).readLine();
>
> }
> ```

Do this instead:

```
public void loadSomething(InputStream in) throws IOException {

 consoleId = getReader(in).readLine();

}
```

Checked exceptions provide a means of ensuring that exceptional conditions are handled. If you don't want to handle them in your method, just declare that they need to be handled in the calling method.

If you really want to mask the exception, then of course:

```
public void loadSomething(InputStream in) {

    try {
        consoleId = getReader(in).readLine(); 
        // ...all of your other code here...
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
```

But I **strongly** recommend not hiding exceptions like that. It usually leads to difficult-to-debug errors.

---

Separately:

- Calling `close` on your `Reader` calls `close` on the `InputStream`. Since you're not in control of the `InputStream`, that's not a good idea. (And yes, this is a bit tricky. You could readily argue that since you own the `Reader`, you should close it. But that's just not how those classes work, for better or ill.)

Comment: throws IOException = throws RuntimeException

Comment: @ses: Well, if you're going to change the question... Yes, you could change all of the checked exceptions into runtime exceptions. Would it be a good idea? Dunno, what style of brace placement / code indentation do you prefer? (E.g., it's a style argument.) I would say, no, it's an awful idea. But that's me.

Comment: @ses: no. IOException is not a runtime exception.

Comment: I know that's why I do not want to use it. See my question. My original question was about to use RuntimeExceptions instead of ChekingExceptions. (i just forgot to put *throws RuntimeException* while writing the question)

Comment: Your original question complained about having to catch the IOException and close the reader. And this answer explains that you don't need (and should not) to do it, because it should be done by the caller. Except for the name of the exception in the throws clause, the suggested code here is the same as what you asked for.

Comment: nope. my original code has IOException. that's what I have now. I do not want to have it. I checked my history of edits, I never said I want to use IOException. I know what I want :). i want to have code short, this possible only with runtime exceptions. i believe that checking exceptions are useless - in most cases (that's why new languages does not use it at all).

Comment: This answer proves that your code can be as short as you asked while still using an IOException. Whether the exception is checked or unchecked, you have to handle it somewhere, and to close the stream somewhere. The same code is necessary, in the same place, whether the exception is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) does something more-or-less like you describe in FileUtils.  Have a look at the readLines method here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)

Comment: That still throws IOException. It is checking exception.. that leads to lots of code, like I had before. But at least it closes the file.